# Why won't the aspx file update on the server after a rebuild

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on an asp.net web form.  Today I did some changes to 3 files:

```
details.aspx
regions.aspx
regions.aspx.cs
```

I rebuilt and published.

One of the aspx files (details.aspx) hasn't changed.  On the server, It is still showing as it was last modified a month ago.

I know I could simply overwrite that one file but I am trying to understand what I did wrong.  Or is it to be expected from Visual Studio (2012) ?

Comment: So, what's your problem? Are you sure you modified details.aspx? Can you compare your published file vs your file under the solution, are they equals?

Comment: Problem is the changes weren't reflected on the server as the aspx file wasn't being updated.  I ended up simply adding a linefeed to my aspx, and republishing again.  But that doesn't tell me why VStudio didn't update the file.

Answer (score 1):

In the publish window go to
Settings -> File Publish Options
and check off Delete all existing files prior to publish.

You could also manually clear all files from the publish folder then republish, but the setting takes care of it automatically.

Comment: This doesn't explain why VStudio didn't update my aspx file on the server but at least it solves the issue... sort of.

Comment: By update on the server I am assuming you mean you are publishing on your local and then dragging and dropping the published files to the server replacing existing ones and adding any new ones. Is this correct? The process that I take to publish to a server is the following: Publish on my local, then use a compare tool to see which files changed between my publish directory and the server directory. Replace all changed files with the new files.

Comment: No, I publish directly on the server.

Comment: Alright, and after publishing when you check the file your saying the code is not updated unless you check the setting that I have right? Since the setting I gave actually wipes and replaces the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the BuildAction set to Content. Select the file in Visual Studio, press F4 and check the BuildAction property.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I wouldn't say it was to be expected.  I'd try publishing to a new folder just to remove any risk of it just trying to publish updated files.  I'd check that the Property on the page in VS is Build Content and not something funny that's causing it not to be copied.